# how can I write a text to speech code which will read the message on each panel in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Here is my code I want to bind to two buttons.How can i get both method to run when i click on the saving or checking button?

```
    saving = wx.Button(self.panel, label = "Savings", pos = (150,240))
    sizer.Add(saving,0,flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    credit = wx.Button(self.panel, label = "Credit", pos = (200,280))
    sizer.Add(credit,0,flag=wx.ALL, border=5)

def withdraw_amount(self, amount, acc_type):
    if acc_type=='saving' and amount<=self.saving_amount:
        self.saving_amount -= amount
    elif acc_type=='chequing' and amount<=self.chequing_amount:
        self.chequing_amount -= amount
    else:
        print("Not Enough Balance or invalid account type!")
        return False
    return True


 def deposite_amount(self, amount, acc_type):
    if acc_type=='saving':
        self.saving_amount += amount
    elif acc_type=='chequing':
        self.chequing_amount += amount
    else:
        print("Invalid account type")
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: No evidence of either a button or a ` while` loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction, for common methods of binding a button to a callback function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label="One")
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event, b_name=self.btn.GetLabel(), b_id=self.btn.GetId(): self.OnButton(event, b_name, b_id) )

        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label="Two")
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2)

        self.btn3 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label="Three")
        self.btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton3)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.btn2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.btn3, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.account_type= "Deposit"

    def OnButton(self, event, button_label, button_id):
        print ("\nInformation provided via a Lambda")
        print ("Button Pressed:", button_label, button_id)

    def OnButton2(self, event):
        button_label = self.btn2.GetLabel()
        button_id = self.btn2.GetId()
        account_type = self.account_type
        print ("\nInformation provided by self.item Query")
        print ("Button2 Pressed:", button_label, button_id)
        print ("Value of account type:", account_type)

    def OnButton3(self, event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        button_label = obj.GetLabel()
        button_id = obj.GetId()
        print ("\nInformation provided via eventobject")
        print ("Button3 Pressed:", button_label, button_id)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, title="Button Bind")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```